# File size nearly doubled after Powershell regex replace?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I am reading json files from a directory and replacing a number of strings and have noticed that the file size after running the script is almost twice the size.  The file has the same number of lines after running, (sometimes one extra line). The replacements are working fine but the folder has thousands of files and the difference after running will be over 100gb!

Just wondering if there is something I've screwed up in the script?

```
Get-ChildItem G:\VaM\Saves\scene\* -recurse -include *.json,*.vap,*.vaj |
    Foreach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName -NoNewLine
    (Get-Content -raw -LiteralPath $_.FullName) |
        Foreach-Object {$_ -Replace '" *:.*/Custom/', '" : "Custom/' -Replace 'male/RG', 'male/kill-RG' -Replace '_MAKEUP', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make up', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make-up', 'Makeup' -Replace '"SELF:/', '"'} |
        Out-File $_.FullName}
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp5Ip.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gwHS.png)

I ran the script a number of times on a small sample and the result is the same.

I'm running windows 11

Comment: It seems your original files are ASCII (1-byte-per-character), but the resulting output is UTF-16 (2-bytes-per-character).  You should put `-encoding ascii` as a parameter to your `Out-File` command.

Comment: @abelenky out-file defaults to utf16, so it would make sense the size would double; I prefer set-content to out-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Set-Content` rather than `Out-File` which may be the culprit here:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'G:\VaM\Saves\scene\*' -Recurse -Include '*.json','*.vap','*.vaj' | & {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
    )
    PROCESS
    {
        (Get-Content -Path $InputObject.FullName -Raw) `
            -Replace '" *:.*/Custom/', '" : "Custom/' -Replace 'male/RG', 'male/kill-RG' -Replace '_MAKEUP', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make up', 'Makeup' -Replace 'Make-up', 'Makeup' -Replace '"SELF:/', '"' |
            Set-Content -Path $InputObject.FullName
    }
}
```

The use of the `Foreach-Object` after your `Get-Content` is unnecessary since `-Raw` is being applied which will read the entire contents as a single multi-line string.